# How to retrieve the minimum date having 3 columns (day), (month) and (year) with RSQLite?

Tags: sql, r, rsqlite

I am working with SQL in R. I want to get the minimum date by choosing the minimum value of the column 'day;, the minimum value of the column 'month' and the minimum value of the column 'year'.

I have tried this by the following code:

```r
dbGetQuery(db, "SELECT day, month, year
                FROM surveys
                WHERE year = (SELECT MIN(year) FROM surveys);")
```

But my output is not one value, how can I get one value in my output and not a list of values?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your query returns rows on the minimum year, not minimum date. Consider generating a date column by concatenating the date parts to identify minimum:

```r
sql = "WITH sub AS (
          SELECT day, month, year
                , DATE(year || '-' ||
                       CASE 
                          WHEN length(month)=1 
                          THEN '0' || month
                          ELSE month
                       END  || '-' ||
                       CASE 
                          WHEN length(day)=1 
                          THEN '0' || day 
                          ELSE day 
                       END) AS [date]
          FROM surveys
      )

      SELECT DISTINCT day, month, year, [date]
      FROM sub
      WHERE [date] = (SELECT MIN([date]) FROM sub)"

dbGetQuery(db, sql)
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/anNLH5HKBuUrVmkPs72M1k/0)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much! It is giving the correct output now.

Comment: This does not work.  The date function requires 2 character  month and day.  Also it can give more than one row as the answer.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, good points. Adjusted accordingly. Elaji, please see edits as `MIN()` would leave out `NULL`s for incorrect `YYYY-MM-DD` generation.

Comment: Suggest `printf('%d-%02d-%02d',year, month, day)`

Answer (score 0):

Using the test data shown we order it by year, month and day and select the first row of the sorted table.

```
library(sqldf)
surveys <- data.frame(year = 2001:2005, month = 5:1, day = 1:5)

sqldf("select day, month, year from surveys order by year, month, day limit 1")
##   day month year
## 1   1     5 2001
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, I am using the following package: library(RSQLite). Is it also possible to run this code with this package?

Comment: Use the same sql.

Comment: Thankyou for you reply, i have found a way to fix the problem!